# происходит переполнение, как это устранить?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a1, a100;
    float d, s;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    cout << "Введите числа: ";
    cin >> a1 >> a100;
    d = (a100 - a1) / 99.0;
    s = (2 * a1 + 15 * d) * 8.0;
    cout << "Разность прогрессии: "<< d << endl;
    cout << "Сумма первых 16 членов прогрессии: " << s;
    return 0;
}
```

C26451  Арифметическое переполнение: использование оператора "-" на байтовом значении 4 и приведение результата к байтовому значению 8. Приведите значение к более широкому типу перед вызовом оператора "-", чтобы избежать переполнения (io.2).

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: если нужно просто предупреждение наивного компилятора убрать, то можно так `d = (a100 - a1) / 99.0f;` - скорее это ровно то, что Вам нужно

Answer (score 2):

Чисто теоретически значение

```
(a100 - a1) / 99.0;
```

имеет тип `double`, который может не поместиться в вашей переменной `d` типа `float`.

Чем вам так дорог именно `float`? Замените его на используемый по умолчанию `double` и не мучайтесь...